# MVC 3 [HttpPost]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I get HttpPost to work???

I'd wrote the following actions to receive my form:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TextAction()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "POST";
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult TextAction(string title)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "GET";
        return View();
    }
```

The Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TextAction", "Admin", FormMethod.Post)){...}
```

Well... it was supposed to write "POST" in the first action View... wasn't it?

Why does it redirecting to the "GET" only?

Help please!

Comment: How are you submitting the form?  Are there any inputs in the form which are being posted back to the server?

Comment: I suggest you read up about GET and POST, because your obviously confused. Otherwise im confused by your question.

Answer (score 1):

If by "first action view" you mean the one that the user first sees when browsing to say "`http://www.mysite.com/Admin/TextAction`". GET is always used when you type something into the address field and type enter, or when you click on a normal `<a>` link.

The most common way to initiate a post action is by having the user click some submit button for a form which have the `method` attribute set to `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

> Well... it was supposed to write "POST" in the first action View... wasn't it?

As alun pointed out above, no.  I think the trouble is with your assumptions about how the HTTP protocol works; it's probably a good idea to read up on it a bit.  Apart from reading up, a nice way to get some practical insight is to use something like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), and check under the "Net" tab.  You will see GETs and POSTs as and when they happen.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that when you are requesting a form to be presented to you, you are GETting the data from the server, but when you fill a form and send it back to server your are POSTing the data. Therefore it is normal for it to say GET in your case if you did not submit the form. The moment you submit the form, the browser will initiate a POST method and your Post version of action would get called.